# Why type-casting don't properly work with $. in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, loops, casting, rational-number, predefined-variables

I have a Ruby code as shown below, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/Pyc/v6C6QEVP29awqPb/fwA)

```
loop{p$.+=1r}
```

and another one, in which I just divide the `1r` by 2 as shown below, [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/Pyc/v6C6QEVP29awSN@o9v9/AA)

```
loop{p$.+=1r/2}
```

As far as I can guess, the type-casting isn't working properly with `$.`. In the first case, it works correctly, but in the second one, it doesn't. *strange!*

So, why it works that way? Or, maybe my guess is wrong, then what is the actual issue, and how to resolve it?

---

Usually, `Integer` are up-casted to more complex data types, [like in this code](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/v0LBVsGQq0ChQkehQi85J7G4mKtCQRsoVqRvhCL8/z8A), it seems to work.

Comment: `x=0r; loop{p x+=1/2r}` works, trying to change the class of the $. variable wont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works correctly, type of the `$.` variable is `Integer`

```
puts $..class. # => Integer
```

So right side of the addition will be casted to the `Integer`.
In first case `1r` is casted to the `Integer` of value `1`, so you can see value is changing.

In second case `1r/2` is casted to the Integer of value `0`, so you don't see changes because adding zero will not change original value.

You can not change type of **pre-defined** global variable, just try `$. = "text"`

Comment: You can not change type of pre-defined global variable, just try `$. = "text"`